# How to know which radiobutton was clicked when ok button is clicked in alertdialog?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have following code for alertdialog:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("Options");
    helpBuilder.setMessage("Choose Your Option");

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View radioButtonLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);
    byNameRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.byname);
    byIdRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.byid);
    helpBuilder.setView(radioButtonLayout);
    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     Toast.makeText(Tab1Activity.this,
                     "Ok button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .show();


                    }


                }
            });

    AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();
```

[image]

I want to know which radiobutton was clicked when ok OK button is clicked ??
Help Needed.
Thanx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the default implementation of Dialog with radio buttons which you can find here : [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) . You won't need to write anything extra as code and you will get what you need! : )
 Here is the example :

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"By Score", "By Name", "By Id"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Options");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: Exactly, the default version is more useful then you with OK button.

Comment: Why didnt this code work ??
`okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
  okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
                          //Above code u mention
                      
    
   }

  });`

On oK button clicked, alertdialog should appear but nothing happens.

Comment: Exact Code I wrote:
`okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
final CharSequence[] items ={ "ByScore", "ByName", "ById" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(Tab1Activity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Options");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
      });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
}});
`

Comment: Because you need to call `alert.show();` so you can show the alert dialog. The code that I gave you only creates the dialog, without showing it : )